# Replace NULL with -1 in all nodes of a binary search tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Given a Binary Search Tree
Instead of making the right or left or both pointers of  nodes point to NULL, make them point to nodes containing data value -1.(the -1 nodes then in turn point to NULL).
Can anyone provide a code snippet for the above, preferably C++.

Comment: Show what you have now and we can probably tell you where to make changes.

Comment: There is no one "snippit". Every place you test for a `NULL` would instead need to test for a signal value of `-1`. Doesn't seem to have much benefit and would only work for nodes that contain an integer.

Comment: As @crashmstr said, allocate a pointer to a dummy node with value -1 and use it everywhere you would otherwise set a downward pointer to `nullptr`. Don't forget about your constructor and destructor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for that is to understand a BST as an array.

Suppose you have this tree, where `-1` represent children that don't exist yet:

[image]

If we understand the children of a node `i` as the nodes `2i + 1` (left child) and `2i + 2` (right child), we can represent such tree as an array like this:

```
[5, 3, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 7, -1, 10]
```

Here's an example of such implementation with the tree above:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct BST{
    int tree[40];
    BST(){for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) tree[i] = -1;}
    
    void add(int value){
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 40 && tree[i] != -1){
            if(tree[i] <= value) i = 2 * i + 2;
            else i = 2 * i + 1; 
        }
        tree[i] = value;
    }
};

int main (){
    BST bst;
    bst.add(5); bst.add(3); bst.add(8); bst.add(2); bst.add(4); 
    bst.add(6); bst.add(9); bst.add(1); bst.add(7); bst.add(10); 
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        if(bst.tree[i] != -1){
            cout<<bst.tree[i]<<": ["<<bst.tree[2 * i + 1]<<", "<<bst.tree[2 * i + 2]<<"]"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT** (node `i`: [left child of `i`, right child of `i`]).

```
5: [3, 8]
3: [2, 4]
8: [6, 9]
2: [1, -1]
4: [-1, -1]
6: [-1, 7]
9: [-1, 10]
1: [-1, -1]
7: [-1, -1]
10: [-1, -1]
```